# Convert a floating point hexadecimal to float in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I converted a floating point number say `1.012` to hexadecimal using Javascript by using the command `1.012.toString(16)` and now what can be done to reverse the output of javascript `1.03126e978d4fe` to `1.012` using Ruby ?

In short, what's the easiest way of reversing a floating point which was encoded as hexadecimal in Ruby?

Thanks.

Comment: "Hexadecimal" and "float" have no business being in the same sentence. That output is completely bonkers.

Comment: @tadman : I was really puzzled at first too. It does make sense though, and is consistent with our base-ten floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This output looked really weird at first, but it's actually consistent with our base-ten floats. `1.012` looks normal to us just because we use the decimal numeral system every day.

If I understand it correctly, the output can be seen as a rational with the numerator being the whole hex number (without '.') and the denominator being `16**(length of "decimal" part)` :

```
def string_to_float(string, base = 10)
  string.delete('.').to_i(base).to_f / base**(string.reverse.index('.') || 0)
end

string_to_float('1.03126e978d4fe', 16)
#=> 1.012

string_to_float('1c.8', 16)
#=> 28.5

string_to_float('3.243f6a8885a3', 16)
#=> 3.141592653589793

string_to_float('20.0', 16)
#=> 32.0

string_to_float('20.', 16)
#=> 32.0

string_to_float('20', 16)
#=> 32.0

string_to_float('3.14159', 10)
#=> 3.14159

string_to_float('11.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011', 2)
#=> 3.141592653589793
```

If you only need to convert hex floats, you can remove the `base` argument :

```
def hex_string_to_float(hex)
  hex.delete('.').to_i(16).to_f / 16**(hex.reverse.index('.') || 0)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the weirdest conversion I ever saw.

```
i, m = "1.03126e978d4fe".split('.')
Integer("0x#{i}") + 1.0 * Integer("0x#{m}") / Integer("0x1#{'0' * m.length}")
#⇒ 1.012
```

Comment: Why `Integer` with all that string hackery and not `.to_i(16)`?

Comment: Ahah. I don't even understand the question, I don't understand the answer, but apparently, you solved it.

Comment: `i.to_i` should be `i.to_i(16)`. `Float(32)` is encoded as `20.0`.

Comment: Your method could be written as `i.to_i(16) + m.to_i(16).to_f/16**m.length` BTW.

Comment: `16**m` is one way. `1<<(4*m)` is another, either of which is better than reepating string prefixed with `0x1` then wrangled into an Integer.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Could you please edit your answer? I upvoted it before noticing that `i.to_i` doesn't work for `i>9`